# Making island nations stand out on world map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology

I'm using ArcGIS Pro to create a world map where the color of each country represents a value from a graduated scale. When you're zoomed at the global scale, it becomes really difficult to see the colors of Samoa, the South Georgia Islands, the French Southern Territories, etc. However, those island nations have some of the highest values on my scale, so I'd really like them to stand out.

How can I format the symbology to do this?

Ideally, I wouldn't have to make a whole ton of inset maps for each set of islands.

Comment: You can apply color to outlines as well, then increase width

Comment: Have you seen this [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17445647.2020.1736194)?

Comment: That's a great paper! I really like the leader lines and squares/circles they use for the symbology of the Caribbean and other SIDS (in this figure specifically: https://figshare.com/articles/journal_contribution/Topographic_and_thematic_in_visibility_of_Small_Island_Developing_States_in_a_world_map/12038586). How would I generate those in ArcGIS Pro? Do I have to separate SIDS from the rest of the countries (which just need a simple fill)?